# Statistics from one image to another in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics, digital-image-processing

I now have two images of the same place, image1 stores image values and each pixel on image 2 stores time (jday).I want to count the sum of image values of image1 at the same time point on image2.For example, there are 10 time points on January 1, 2000 on image2, and I want to get the sum of these 10 positions image1.The final result is presented in the form of a table or chart.

Here is my example code https://code.earthengine.google.com/0db5219ac3e642d9ac28c73e20c6e7cb

Hope you can answer this question